# OpenVPN Tunneling On Local Network Only?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have two IP addresses: 10.200.0.5 and 10.200.0.6 and I would like to connect the two via an OpenVPN tunnel (one belongs to a Windows 7 PC, the other a Fedora laptop). Is there a way to do this using just the internal, network, addresses, the gateway address, and the subnet, *ie*: with **no requirement whatsoever** for an internet address or remote connection (as in an outside of my local network remote connection)?

**05.03.2018:** further to *grawity*'s comment I need to explain that the problem I was having is with the **remote** directive: even in the Static Key Mini-HOWTO ( https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html ) that requirement is there, and it is that that is causing the problem because, unless I can create a local domain on either my linux box or my Windows PC for it to resolve to, then it will fail.

As I have been completely unable to create a domain and to get it resolving as a local domain (even with a working BIND *named* service on the linux box), then, logically, the solution is to stick to local (network) IP addresses; only the **remote** directive will not accept that and, hence, my question.

**05.03.2018:** would have posted an update and final, solved, reply had the forum not been configured to put a block on my updates with some highly patronising *"take a breather"* nonsense. - Three lines of code required, one person commenting with none-too-helpful comments, and the forum blocks my attempts to add more material to the post, which was with the intention of enabling other people to have a clearer idea of what the problem is, and which is something the self-same forum *encourages and recommends* in the first place!! ...all because no-one else can be bothered to help with the absolutely basic, beginner, problems I have been having with this and BIND.

...and what of people like myself (of which there are clearly many thousands of) who need to get something resolved one way or the other and are just as prepared to add their efforts if someone would but help with the absolute basics of how to get their problem resolved, when they have already tried using whatever other resources there may be and have been completely unsuccessful in making any progress with that material (as with myself, where OpenVPN's complete failure to fully detail some of their configuration options can create a near-insurmountable problem in getting even the most basic of configurations to work).

Anyway, no matter, be that as it may, **this** is the final (working) solution for anyone needing to connect two machines using network addresses only (no domain configurations and absolutely **no** remote network or *example.com* connections whatsoever), with both machines on the same subnet. This is also about the simplest possible connection for anyone looking to get started using OpenVPN.

**Setup:**

1x Windows personal computer (running Windows 7 Pro x64)

1x Fedora 27 Server Edition laptop

Both machines connected via a router on the same LAN and able to communicate with each other (port 1194 - unless configured to be something different). My setup uses VLAN separation with static IPv4 for security considerations and in order to give me an additional IP address; but the additional IP address could also be created through a standalone static IPv4 address added to the ethernet adapter with no VLAN.

- OpenVPN installed on both machines, with the repository version (*ie*: not built from source on the machine, but downloaded via **Yum**) installed on the linux box
- *static.key* file generated on the linux box using: `openvpn --genkey --secret static.key`
- the above file on my linux box is located in: **/etc/openvpn/server** or the OpenVPN **\config** sub-directory on the Windows machine.
- *sample.ovpn* [*v.i.*] is stored in an ASCII text file (Notepad / Notepad++ as an editor, *not* Microsoft Word!) as an *.ovpn* file within the OpenVPN **\config** sub-directory on the Windows machine and as a *.conf* file in **/etc/openvpn/server** on the linux box.
- OpenVPN GUI (Start Button - round object with Windows logo to the bottom left of the screen - All Programs - OpenVPN) is then initiated on the Windows machine, resulting in a small icon in the system tray to the bottom right of the screen (screen as viewed by the user). The *.ovpn* config file should then be accessible and editable by right clicking on the icon in order to select it, likewise with the log file.
- *vpntest.conf* is instantiated on the linux box with `openvpn vpntest.conf`, and as detailed above on the Windows machine.

All being well a tunnel will now be established between the two machines, and it will be possible to open an instance of CMD (command-line) on the Windows machine in order to *ping* the linux box. The linux box will require further configuration in order to make OpenVPN run in the background before it will be possible to *ping* the client, as it will otherwise remain in the foreground; effectively rendering the machine unusable for anything beyond those services already running in the background.

**Observations:**

OpenVPN on the Windows side uses a TAP adapter. This makes no difference to whether or not your config is using TAP or TUN, and should not prevent this simple configuration from working.

The two *ifconfig* IP addresses are not configured on my router, and there is absolutely no need for me to reconfigure my router at all in order to allow their use. - They are part of the same 255.255.255.0 subnet as the other two 10.200.0 addresses (10.200.0.5 and 10.200.0.6), so OpenVPN is allowed to use them via the OpenVPN adapter and DHCP.

The names of the config files follow no mandatory naming conventions beyond common sense, *.ovpn* file extension on the Windows machine, and a *.conf* file extension on the linux box.

OpenVPN is *extremely* pissy about what subnets it will work on, and will even refuse to work on subnets that are allowed under **show-valid-subnets**. Using non-sequential addresses within a subnet is also highly likely to result in failed connection attempts.

Beware of *firewalld* and SELinux. SELinux can be tamed until reboot with <strike>satanforce</strike>, sorry, *setenforce permissive*, and in its **/etc/selinux** *.conf* file. I have a firewall and anti-spoof protection both running on the router with no problem, along with a software firewall on the Windows machine, a remote VPN connection, and occasional SSh connections to the linux machine; all of which co-exist quite happily together.

VLAN configuration can involve configuration via the default network adapter on Windows, following initial configuration on the router. Windows 7 does not like tagged VLAN, so an untagged VLAN0 may be a requirement. It is also likely that it will only be possible to add an untagged VLAN0 on the network adapter side following the initial creation of a tagged VLAN1. This is true of Intel adapters, and Windows will need to be connected to the untagged port on the router following VLAN configuration of the router.

On a Fedora box the *Fedora Administrator's Guide* covers VLAN creation. It is slightly ambiguous in one part, but the end result, if followed carefully, does work, and works for tagged VLANS, too.

**sample.ovpn:**

```
dev tun
remote 10.200.0.6
ifconfig 10.200.0.1 10.200.0.2
secret static.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-tun
persist-key
```

**vpntest.conf**

```
dev tun
remote 10.200.0.5
ifconfig 10.200.0.2 10.200.0.1
user nobody
group nobody
secret static.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-tun
persist-key
```

**sample.log**

```
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 disabling NCP mode (--ncp-disable) because not in P2MP client or server mode
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Sep 26 2017
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7) 64bit
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017, LZO 2.10
Enter Management Password:
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 open_tun
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 TAP-WIN32 device [Local Area Connection 6] opened: \\.\Global\{B1A13B50-22A1-48D4-980B-7105480DBA9B}.tap
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.200.0.1/255.255.255.252 on interface {B1A13B50-22A1-48D4-980B-7105480DBA9B} [DHCP-serv: 10.200.0.2, lease-time: 31536000]
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 Successful ARP Flush on interface [15] {B1A13B50-22A1-48D4-980B-7105480DBA9B}
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]10.200.0.6:1194
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 UDP link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
Tue Mar 06 00:34:27 2018 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]10.200.0.6:1194
Tue Mar 06 00:34:36 2018 Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]10.200.0.6:1194
Tue Mar 06 00:34:41 2018 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Tue Mar 06 00:34:41 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is nothing in OpenVPN that *would* require any sort of Internet access; it is not a "cloud service" or anything such.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of that, - I know that, in theory, a public internet address should only be required if I wish to establish a connection between two remote networks; so why, then, the need for a _remote_ directive? - If I omit it, the connection cannot be established, if I change it to a local network IP address then likewise.

Comment: This answers my question, but was not at all helpful in enabling me to resolve the problem; however, that said, I have now managed to get something working, with a ping-able tunnel, but need to resolve further issues before posting my working solution.

Comment: The `remote` directive does not imply anything about Internet nor public addresses. It means "the other end of the connection".

Comment: Noted, but, no offence intended, I do feel that either you know as little as I do about configuring OpenVPN, or you are being deliberately vague and posting contrary to the forum guidelines on helping people (three lines of simple code - the OpenVPN minimum requirement - as a post would be trivial to anyone with any understanding of OpenVPN configuration).